# How to type in text box in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I used `sendKeys` method, first time when I ran my script it worked but from second time it is not working. Script is finding the element but not entering in text box.

Please suggest if there is any other way to enter text in text box. and why it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='logcomments']")).size()); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='logcomments']")).sendKeys("Log_Testing"); // textBox 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='postLog']/img")).click(); //enter button
```

HTML code :

```
<div style="position:relative;top:40px;"> 
  <div> 
   <span id="actualcommentCount">1</span> 
   <span> Comments </span> 
 </div> 
  <div> 
   <textarea id="logcomments" type="text" style="resize:none; width:80%;" placeholder="Comments"> </textarea> 
   <span id="postLog"> 
     <img style="cursor:pointer;width:45px;color:#337ab7;float: right;margin-top:-5px; margin-right:10px;font-size:30px;" src="images/poll_fly.png"> 
   </span> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by second time??? you run your test case second time or same test case use same code second time??? and Is there any exception during second time???

Comment: @SaurabhGaur : I ran same script again. I didn't get any error or exception. script ran completely without any error but text is not entered in text box.

Comment: is it happen occasionally or every second time run???

Comment: Did you tried `WebDriverWait` untill `textbox` visible???

Comment: Try once like `WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("logcomments"));el.click();el.sendKeys("Log_Testing");`.. and let me know..

Comment: yes, it worked but i don't understand why previous code was not working.What was wrong in that?

Comment: yes , I used WebDriverWait .

Comment: Please see my answer I gave you the reason..:)

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the `HTML` of the page?

You could try :-

```
driver.findElement(By.id("logcomments")).sendKeys("Some Text");
```

What `error` are you getting when you run the test?

Comment: HTML code : 

<div style="position:relative;top:40px;">
<div>
<span id="actualcommentCount">1</span>
<span> Comments </span>
</div>
<div>
<textarea id="logcomments" type="text" style="resize:none; width:80%;" placeholder="Comments"> </textarea>
<span id="postLog">
<img style="cursor:pointer;width:45px;color:#337ab7;float: right;margin-top:-5px; margin-right:10px;font-size:30px;" src="images/poll_fly.png">
</span>
</div>
</div>

Comment: @user2036787 you need to post this HTML into your question as well

Answer (score 1):

You should try as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("logcomments"));
el.click();
el.sendKeys("Log_Testing");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='postLog']/img")).click();
```

**Note** :- You need to `focus` on `text area` before set value so need to use `el.click()` to focus on `text area` because when you try to `.sendKeys()` it goes to set value but due to focus is not on `text area` it could not be set.

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type on keyboard then you need to use robot class as below. But ensure you have already clicked on textbox before you start typing.

```
typeKeysStringUsingRobotClass("hey123");
}

public void typeKeysStringUsingRobotClass(String text){
  String[] arr = text.split("");
  for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
     keyPressUsingRobotClass(arr[i]);
}

public void keyPressUsingRobotClass(String key){
  Robot rb = new Robot();
  if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){ rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){ rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B); rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_B);
  .
  .
  .
  if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){ rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0); rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try with javaScript executed to add text to the text box.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
jsExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementById('logcomments').value='Yourvalue is here'");
```

And also, plz post if there is an exception or error is there. Without that, it is hard to find a solution.

Comment: you should ask for "exceptions and errors" before posting your answer, please consider puting your answer as a coment